# In iOS what is the proper way to remove all custom annotations and add new custom annotations?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am successfully adding custom annotations to my MKMapView and successfully removing them. I am using a sub view controller to filter the annotations on my map view. When I remove all the annotations I am having problems adding the new annotations to the map view. The correct data is being added to my array of annotations, but the annotations do not make it to the map view when I add the annotations using my array. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

It is probably worth noting that when I place a break point on custom annotation if statement it gets called the first time I add annotations to the map view, but not the second time.

This is where I add the annotations:

```
for (placesChamber *placesObject in placesChamberArray) {

    if ([placesObject.category isEqualToString:@"COC"]) {

        tealAnnotation *annotationTeal = [[tealAnnotation alloc] init];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([placesObject.latitude doubleValue],[placesObject.longitude doubleValue]);


        annotationTeal.coordinate = coordinates;

        annotationTeal.title = placesObject.name;

        annotationTeal.tealAnnotationClass = placesObject;

        [placesMapPointsArray addObject:annotationTeal];
    }

}

[placesMapView addAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];

NSLog(@"Number of Places found: %lu",(unsigned long)placesMapPointsArray.count);

NSLog(@"Number of Places on map: %lu",(unsigned long)placesMapView.annotations.count);

if (!placesMapView.annotations || !placesMapView.annotations.count) {
    NSLog(@"There are 0 annotations.");

}//end if
```

This is for my custom annotation using: (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[tealAnnotation class]]) // for
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString *TealAnnotationIdentifier = @"tealPin";

        MKPinAnnotationView *tealPinView =
        (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.placesMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:TealAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (tealPinView == nil)
        {
            // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
            MKPinAnnotationView *tealAnnotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:TealAnnotationIdentifier];

            tealAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"teal_pin.png"];
            tealAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            tealAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            CGSize newSize;
            newSize.width = 32;
            newSize.height = 32;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
            [tealAnnotationView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
            UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            tealAnnotationView.image = newImage;

            return tealAnnotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            tealPinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return tealPinView;
    }
```

Here is how I am removing the annotations:

```
[placesMapView removeAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];
[placesMapPointsArray removeObjectsInArray:placesMapPointsArray];
```

After getting information from comments I have noticed that the viewDelegate for my mapView has changed to "nil".

Comment: Try changing `[placesMapView removeAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];` to `[placesMapView removeAnnotations:placesMap.annotations];`

Comment: @JoeFryer Did not work. Still did not add annotations to the map view.

Comment: Which `if` statement isn't being triggered the second time around?

Comment: @JaiGovindani `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[tealAnnotation class]])`

Comment: oh ok so it's kind of obvious why the annotations aren't being added, since you're not hitting that code. The main question is, why are the annotations not the type you're expecting. Place a breakpoint right on the `if` statement (not inside) and when it hits that, in your debugger, do a `po theMapView.annotations` to see what kind of annotations are in your map view's annotations array

Comment: Does your first code snippet get called twice? We see where you remove the annotations, where is the bit where you add in the second lot that never get drawn? And could the removal bit be happening after you add them the second time but before they get drawn?

Comment: @JaiGovindani I tried you method and placed a couple of different break points with `po placesMapView.annotations` to see what kind of annotations were being used. On the second time `[placesMapView addAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];` returned `nil` and right after it returned `nil`, Also on the second time `else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[tealAnnotation class]])` is never called. This is most likely because I am getting `nil` for my po placesMapView.annotations.

Comment: @Craig yes it does get called twice. The first snippet is part of a method that gets called again. I do not believe the removal bit is happening after this gets called. I have a filter button that presents a sub view and at that time I remove the annotations. I call the method that adds the annotations again when the user closes the sub view. I think it is narrowed down to `[placesMapView addAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];` or the array creation in the first snippet being the problem.

Comment: @JaiGovindani When I `po placesMapPointsArray` on `[placesMapView addAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray];` it returns my tealAnnotation class, but not for `po placesMapView.annotations` it returns `nil`.

Comment: What do the two NSLog statements say during this process. There should be at least four lines printed out showing whether there were any annotations to add and if hey got added.

Comment: @Craig On the first round `NSLog(@"Number of Places found: %lu",(unsigned long)placesMapPointsArray.count);` returns "Number of Places found: (a number here)" and `NSLog(@"Number of Places on map: %lu",(unsigned long)placesMapView.annotations.count);` returns its output with the same number and no outputs for `if (!placesMapView.annotations || !placesMapView.annotations.count) {
        NSLog(@"There are 0 annotations.");
        
    }//end if`. On the second round I get "Number of Places found: (a number)", "Number of Places on map: 0" and "There are 0 annotations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comments the problem is clearly that `placesChamberArray` does not have any objects with a category of 'COC' on the second run. If it did the placesMapPointsArray would have to have some items but the NSLOg statement says it doesn't. You can verify this by putting an NSLog after `isEqualToString` and showing that it isn't running.

Comment: Craig, thanks for the answer, but the placesChamberArray creates the placesMapPointsArray with a for loop. I am able to see that placesMapPointsArray has the correct number of objects, correct data and applies it to the correct tealAnnoationClass. But it never gets to the map.

Comment: I misread your comment. You say that placesMapPointsArray does have items, but calling addAnnotations and then annotations.count returns 0. That sounds impossible to me. There must be more code at work here.

Comment: Turns out it was the [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) that I was using for my filter. Once I removed this it worked. I think it was un-delegating my map view and not allowing me to place new annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `[placesMapView addAnnotations:placesMapPointsArray]` again after you added new objects into the array?

Comment: Please refer to the comment by myself in reference to **Craig's** question as a reply to your answer-question.